# Cannot find module 'postcss-preset-env' error using create-react-app inside an npm workspace

Tags: create-react-app, postcss, monorepo, npm-workspaces, turborepo

I'm trying to add a `create-react-app` app inside a Turborepo monorepo.

Problem is that if I run `npm install` from the root of the monorepo and then try to start the CRA app by running `npm run dev`, I get the following error during compile time:

> Loading PostCSS "postcss-preset-env" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'postcss-preset-env'

I noticed that if I run `npm install` from within the CRA app folder (`/apps/my-app`), and then run `npm run dev` from the root of the monorepo, it runs just fine.

I also noted that depending from where I run `npm install`, the contents of `/apps/my-app/node_modules` will be different, but I think is the expected behaviour.

If I understand correctly the [npm workspaces docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces), you should always run `npm install` from the root of the monorepo.

Any idea on what I'm missing here?

I'm using npm 8.3.1.

Here is a public repo with an example: https://github.com/oncet/turborepo-cra